# Count of total telephone calls within each of three time ranges Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, union

I'm a noob at this and usually deconstruct other SQL programs to better help me understand Access programming.

I have a table (Table1) which, among other basic information facts, records the Date and the Time a call is received. Our office hours are between 4:30pm and 8:30pm.

What I am trying to learn is how to print out on a report the number of calls (Count) that fall between: 4:30 and 6:29, 6:30 and 8:29, 8:30 and 10:30.

It should look like this on the bottom of the report:

Number of Calls per shift

Call Count: 4:30 to 6:29    (n)
Call Count: 6:30 to 8:29    (n)
Call Count: 8:30 to 10:30   (n)

I keep getting an error message about a Reserved word in the SELECT

Comment: Please include the code you've attempted and the exact error.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've used the word "Count" without properly quoting it. As showdev says, we need to see what you did to help you know what you did wrong.

Comment: here are the two queries that I am trying to join through "UNION"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT "4:30 PM TO 6:29 PM" AS TimeCalc, Count(Q.Call_ID) AS TotalCalls
FROM Table1 AS Q
WHERE Q.Call_Time >=#4:30 PM#
AND Q.Call_Time <=#6:29 PM#
UNION
SELECT "6:30 PM TO 8:29 PM" AS TimeCalc, Count(Q.Call_ID) AS TotalCalls
FROM Table1 AS Q
WHERE Q.Call_Time >=#6:30 PM#
AND Q.Call_Time <=#8:29 PM#
UNION
SELECT "8:30 PM TO 10:30 PM" AS TimeCalc, Count(Q.Call_ID) AS TotalCalls
FROM Table1 AS Q
WHERE Q.Call_Time >=#8:30 PM#
AND Q.Call_Time <=#10:30 PM#
```

Just replace `Call_ID` and `Call_Time` with the field names you have and replace `YourTableName` with the tables name.

Here is an example of the results you should see:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your idea works. However, your method uses only two of the fields in my table, and query. But when I try to unite (UNION) your Query to my Query I get and error message because both queries don't contain the same number of fields.

I'm away form my home computer so unfortunately I cannot copy & paste the Query SQL, but it's basically just all the fields on the table with a criteria of Between {Start Date] AND [End Date] for the Time field.

These are the fields in my table (Table1) and query:

Date, Location,Incoming/Outgoing,Time, Duration,Satisfaction,Comments
I tried adding them to your query but Access won't accept it.

Again, it's probably something really simple that I am overlooking.

My Report is set up to automatically display: a monthly count of Incoming and Outgoing phone calls based on the count of dates entered, a count of total Incoming and Outgoing minutes, a count of calls from each location;among other counts.

I'm trying to make the report also automatically a breakdown of total calls divided into three segments: 4:30 to 6:29, 6:30 to 8:29, and 8:30 to 10:30, if that help you understand what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
SELECT MSys_obj.Date, MSys_obj.Location,    MSys_obj[Incoming/Outgoing],MSys_obj.Duration,      
MSys_obj.Satisfaction, MSys_obj.A, MSys_obj.B, MSys_obj.C, MSys_obj.D, MSys_obj.E
```

FROM MSys_obj
   WHERE (((MSys_obj.Date) Between [Start Date] And [End Date]));

```
And ...

SELECT "4:30 PM TO 6:29 PM" AS TimeCalc, Count(Q.Time) AS TotalCalls
FROM MSys_obj
WHERE Q.Time >=#4:30 PM#
AND Q.Time <=#6:29 PM#
UNION
SELECT "6:30 PM TO 8:29 PM" AS TimeCalc, Count(Q.Time) AS TotalCalls
FROM MSys_obj
WHERE Q.Time >=#6:30 PM#
AND Q.Time <=#8:30 PM#
UNION SELECT "8:30 PM TO 10:30 PM" AS TimeCalc, Count(Q.Time) AS TotalCalls
FROM MSys_obj
WHERE Q.Time>= #8:30 PM#
AND Q.Time <=#10:30 PM#;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a lot of problems understanding how to use this website.

Okay, let's try posting this problem again.

Here are the two queries I'm trying to use in a report:

```
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
SELECT MSys_obj.Date, MSys_obj.Location, MSys_obj.[Incoming/Outgoing],   
MSys_obj.Duration, MSys_obj.Satisfaction, MSys_obj.A, MSys_obj.B, MSys_obj.C,  
MSys_obj.D, MSys_obj.E
FROM MSys_obj
WHERE (((MSys_obj.Date) Between [Start Date] And [End Date]));
```

---

```
SELECT "4:30 PM TO 6:29 PM" AS TimeCalc, Count(Q.Date) AS TotalCalls
FROM MSys_obj
WHERE Q.Time >=#4:30 PM#
AND Q.Time <=#6:29 PM#
UNION
SELECT "6:30 PM TO 8:29 PM" AS TimeCalc, Count(Q.Date) AS TotalCalls
FROM MSys_obj
WHERE Q.Time >=#6:30 PM#
AND Q.Time <=#8:30 PM#
UNION SELECT "8:30 PM TO 10:30 PM" AS TimeCalc, Count(Q.Date) AS TotalCalls
FROM MSys_obj
WHERE Q.Time>= #8:30 PM#
AND Q.Time <=#10:30 PM#;
```

---

These are the columns in my table which I had to hide under the name MSys_obj; it's a long story:

Incoming/Outgoing, Date, Worker, Caller, Sex, Time, Duration, Location, Reason, A, B, C, D, E

When I try to merge both queries using SQL, I get an error about the columns count not matching.

Also, the second query doesn't give a correct count from the report, it  displays an entry field requesting a Q.Date and Q.Time, which I don't want, and then displays the three different segments with 0 for each count.

Once again, I am trying to get the original report now to additionally display the count of calls broken down into three sequential time ranges.

All someone should have to do to pull a report is enter the desired date range in the two boxes that appear, one for Start Date and one for End Date and the report will display all it's data including the newly added three time ranges.